# Magento show only specific stores

Tags: php, magento, module, web

I have a Magento multi-store website.
I have three stores, all active/enabled.
If I go to footer, "Select Store", all three stores appear, but I want to show only two stores there. The third store should only appear when user is logged in/authenticated.

I can hard-code this file:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/stores.phtml
```

but I don't want this. Is there any way to make this change from admin? Something like adding a flag to the store I don't want to appear.

Comment: Did you know there is a Magento SE site? Currently in beta: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i didn't received answers there for lots of  questions.., here more coders see the questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this situation.
I created a foreach loop and I check if the user is logged in.
If the user is logged in, all stores appear.
If not, only some stores appear.

I created a module in order to avoid core files modification.